# Java Socket issue, buffer receives two packets at same time.

Tags: java, sockets, packet

I am using Java Socket API for communication. But sometime I am getting, packet attached in single packet. How can I avoid the same. Is there any method to resolve same in Java NIO or java NIO 2. I am sure that packets are coming separately. But both stored in single buffer.

Please note that here Packet is nothing but logical separation of data. The data is send by third party system. They send one by one. But I am receiving two packet at same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way it's supposed to work. TCP uses packets to transfer data, but it's not visible from the high-level socket API : you open a output stream and send as much data as you want. This data is split into packets by the TCP/IP protocol stack. And at the receiving side, you open an input stream and receive the data, without knowing it has been split into packets.

If you want two application-level packets, then design a transfer protocol using separators between your packets, or fixed-size chunks of data, or anything else allwoing to distinguish what is part of a logical packet and what is part of the next one.

Comment: +1: In short you have just a stream of bytes.  Any notion of packets or messages is an illusion you need to add.

Comment: I mean packet means messages. It is send by third party system.

Comment: @Kamahire: If they are send by third party system, they should have some format, and you need to parse it.

Comment: Yes, There is. Each Message has specific size.